# Avoiding a divide by zero error in a computed column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, computed-column

How do you avoid divide by zero error in the below table?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDivision]
(
    [Numerator] int NOT NULL,
    [Denominator] int NOT NULL,
    [Result] AS (Numerator/ Denominator)
)
GO
Insert into (Numerator, Denominator) TblDivision values (3,0)
GO
```

Comment: If it is invalid for Denominator to be zero you could add a check constraint on that column. That doesn't answer the question though as it only results in a more meaningful error (closer to the source of the problem) rather than avoiding an error completely.

Comment: Do you intend to use integer division here or not?

Comment: Have you considered not allow 0 to be a value in that column? Typically what I've seen is a sproc being used for client applications, rather than plain SQL.

Answer (score 11):

Just add a special case for division by 0:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDivision]
  (
  [Numerator] int NOT NULL,
  [Denominator] int NOT NULL,
  [Result] AS case when Denominator=0 then 0 else (Numerator/ Denominator) end
  );
```

Comment: Or perhaps return NULL rather than 0 if NULLs are not a problem for code reading that column, as the result of divide-by-zero isn't really 0 unless the numerator is 0.

Comment: Yeah, left as an exercise for the OP, to be honest. Avoiding the error has been answered :)

Answer (score 10):

Similar to @Phil's solution:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TblDivision
(    Numerator int NOT NULL
,    Denominator int NOT NULL
,    Result AS Numerator / nullif(Denominator,0)
);
```

If Denominator is 0 it is mapped to null via nullif. Since anything divided by null is null the result becomes null in this case.

Comment: Of course this is the cleanest solution. I would accept this one.

Answer (score -2):

```
case 
 when Denominator=0 then 0 
 else Numerator/ Denominator 
end as [Result]
```